# "a" vs 'new String("a")' vs 'new String("a").intern()' in String Constant Pool (JDK 6)

Tags: java, string, jvm

I used to know that both of the following statements create the string `a` in the constant pool at runtime:

```
String s = "a"
String s = new String("a")
```

When testing these on the JVM, permgen size is the same for both cases.

---

The following code snippets, however, behave differently from this:

```
String s2 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    s2 = s2 + i;
}
```

Using `.intern()`, the permgen size increases in each iteration:

```
String s2 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    s2 = s2 + i;
    s2.intern();
}
```

---

Why is this behaviour observable? Does `s2.intern()` add entries to the pool? How is this different from these declarations?

```
String s = "a"
String s = new String("a")
```

Comment: `intern()` adds to the string literal pool as this is it's sole purpose as documented.  I am not clear on what the confusion is.

Comment: i use jvisualVM  to check..Using .intern(), the permgen size increases in each iteration.the others  were not ..why ???

Comment: Objects are placed on the heap by default, that is what it is for.  It should be no surprise that Strings are objects and when they are allocated they are placed on the heap.  However when you `intern()` a string you place it in the String literal pool which is in the perm gen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462638/a-vs-new-string-b-in-constant-pool-jvm-jdk-6-eager-for-the-truth

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say with the link. BTW the perm gen is not got, it was replaced with a meta space which serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a little explanation:

- `"a"` create the String *"a"* in the intern pool if not already present
- `new String("a")` because the parameter is *"a"*, the string *"a"* is created in the intern pool (if not already present) and a copy of *"a"* is created out of intern pool
- taken any string s `s.intern()` returns an intern copy of that string if present in the intern pool. If not add that string to the intern pool and returns the new copy.

A reference for [intern()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) method:

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this
>   String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String
>   object is returned.

**Note:** to create a `String` and **don't add it to the intern pool** you can **use an array of chars as parameter of String constructor**:

```
char[] helloArray = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
String helloString = new String(helloArray);
```

Here is the reference to the [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) where it is explained that a string literal is present in the intern pool of strings:

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class String (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because **string literals** - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - **are "interned"**
>   so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

---

Here a step by step explanation to the last comment:

```
// Creates the string "123", add it to the intern pool and assign "123" to s
String s = "123";  

// s.intern() returns the intern string of s. Because s is already the 
// string "123" present in the intern pool s and s.intern() are the same
System.out.println(s == s.intern());// true 

// "123" is already in intern pool. new String("123") create a new String
// that equals "123" but it is a different object
String s2 = new String("123"); 

// It prints false because s2 is equals to "123", but not the same object
// because a new String was created in the preciding row
System.out.println(s2 == s);// false

// It prints true because s2.intern() returns the string present in the
// intern pool that is equals to s2. That string exists and is "123"
System.out.println(s2.intern() == s);  // true
```

**Additional note:** For every string s that equals s2, s.intern() == s2.intern() also if s == s2 returns false.

```
// If s equals s2 but are not the same
if (s.equals(s2) && s != s2) {
    // THe intern string of s and s2 are always the same
    System.out.println(s.intern() == s2.intern()); // prints always true
}
```

Comment: i use jvisualVM  to check..Using .intern(), the permgen size increases in each iteration.the others  were not ..why ???

Comment: Yes because you create the literal "a"

Comment: how can you prove  that???  i thought new String("a") maybe not!  if you can ,i 'll apprecia it

Comment: I add a reference to the jls

Comment: JLS = Java Language Specification, it is the specification that explains what is java and how it works. It is necessary to build the java compiler for example.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/lexical.html#3.10.5 @Davide   it's different in JDK6

Comment: It changes only the graphic aspect and reference numbers, not the concept. Here is the reference from Java 6: "Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1, §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value. String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Comment: i can't understand jls clearly!pelase help me !  why? false： public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String s = "123";
        System.out.println(s == s.intern());// true

        String s2 = new String("123");

        System.out.println(s2 == s);// false

    }

Comment: I add an explanation in the answer

Comment: but why this code is not  Pergen OutMemory????                                                          public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (;;) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                s.add(new String("" + i));
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: please help !! i really want to figure it out........TKS again! @Davide Lorenzo MARINO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462638/a-vs-new-string-b-in-constant-pool-jvm-jdk-6-eager-for-the-truth

Answer (score 0):

Since interned Strings are interned JVM-wide, they must be interned statically, which would require the mechanism to use a *class* attribute for the caching, which would consume permgen memory.